# Grails best way to iterate all ids of a domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have code like this:

```
Book.list().each {
  // real code actually does something more useful
  println "My id is " + it.id
}
```

It strikes me as a bit of a waste that the entire object of each Book is being loaded just to access the id. There is a load() method in Grails for when you only want to operate on the ID and I'm wondering if there's an equivalent here for loading all the domain instances? Should I use HQL? Or should I just leave it as-is?

PS: It makes me wonder whether there should be a option available to most GORM methods (finders etc) which cause it to only "load" instead of "get" the target class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use hql to just return the fields you need

`Book.executeQuery( "select b.id from Book b" );`

Comment: I'd say using `namedQueries` or criteria queries are much better than SQL for readability's sake, especially as your queries grow more complex.

Answer (score 9):

A criteria query in combination with a projection solves your problem when you want to avoid using HQL.

```
    def criteria = Book.createCriteria()
    def result = criteria.list {
        projections {
            property 'id'
        }
    }
```

The Hibernate SQL logging shows that only the IDs are loaded from the database, and not the entire Books: `select this_.id as y0_ from book this_`.

The criteria query can also be added as a [named query](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) on the Book domain class, providing easy access to the list of IDs.

Answer (score 5):

+1 For @Ruben's answer, but you could shorten it up to simply

```
def criteria = Book.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property 'id'
    }
}
```

and get the same results!

Answer (score -2):

Unless the Book object contains a lot of data, I would just go with Book.list to keep it simple.

Remember that *load()* does not actually hit the database, it just constructs an object with the id set.

Comment: i just tried load and it seems to be hitting the database if you try to access any property other than the id.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason to use .load instead of just new Book(id:2), it creates a proxy object that lazy loads the object on access.

Comment: I would agree that if the Book class does not have a lot of data (less than 100k) Using Book.list() is probably ok.

Comment: @aldrin load is not intended for use if you need more than the id.